# Save File and then send it by mail

Tags: android, save, attachment, send

I try to save a textfile and then want to send it as an attachment by mail. 
I can save the file but when i will sent it with "Extra_Stream" the mobile phone says, that it can't send the file.

```
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"muellerswickrath@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Zeiterfassung");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(monteur.getText().toString() + " - Auftrag: " + auftrag.getText().toString() + "\n");

sb.append("*** Start *** \n");
for (int w = 0; w < x; w++) {
    sb.append(list.get(w).toString());
    sb.append("\n");
}
sb.append("*** Ende ***");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());


String filename =  "muellers.xml";
String senden = "Testdatei";


FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(senden.toString().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filename));
```

Can you help me?

Greets from Germany
Wolfgang

Comment: maybe try Uri.fromFile(fileName);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the intent I used to send a attached file:

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```